# How to Mock microservices in Junit

Tags: junit, mockito, microservices, spring-boot-test

**I need to run the integration test of one microservice, without the need to start the dependent microservices.**

Below is the approach I have tried(I have provided the skeleton of the classes below)

**MicroServiceOneController.java**

```
@Autowired
MicroServiceOneService microServiceOneServiceImpl;

@PostMapping(value = "/saveData/{userEmail}")
public void doHandleSaveData(
  @PathVariable("userEmail") String userEmail) {
    microServiceOneService.saveData(userEmail);
}
```

**MicroServiceOneServiceImpl.java**

```
@Autowired
MicroServiceTwoProxy microServiceTwoProxy;

@Override
public void saveData(String userEmail){
  DemoDTO dtoObject=microServiceTwoProxy.fetchRequiredData();
  dtoObject.setUserEmail(userEmail);
  // other code to persist dtoObject
}
```

**TestOfMicroServiceOne.java:**

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class TestOfMicroServiceOne{

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @MockBean
    MicroServiceTwoProxy microServiceTwoProxy;
    
    @test
    void test(){
      Mockito.when(microServiceTwoProxy.fetchRequiredData()).thenReturn(new DemoDTO("1","data"));
    
      HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
      HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
      ResponseEntity<DemoDTO.class> response = 
       this.restTemplate.exchange("/persist/saveData/{userEmail}",
        HttpMethod.POST, entity, DemoDTO.class, "user@gmail.com");
      assertEquals(response.getStatusCode(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

I expected when running the test, when the `microServiceTwoProxy.fetchRequiredData()` is hit, it should return the new DemoDTO("1","data") as specified in the test.

I want this requirement to run the test of MicroserviceOne without depending upon the status of MicroServiceTwo.

But this doesn't seem to work. It expects the second microservices to be up and test fails with the message  `Load balancer does not have available server for client`
Any other approaches available?

Comment: What do you mean by "Bit this doesn't seem to work."? What did you expect the test to do and how does it fail?

Comment: @StefanBirkner I have updated my question to clarify what is expected. Basically, what I expect is, even if the second microservice is down, it should return me a dummy data and intergration test should work  fine.

Comment: @StefanBirkner I think I have a problem regarding the same topic. I still cannot fix it. I hope you can help me .Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74737014/spring-boot-microservice-junit-controller-test-cannot-call-url-of-another-mo